# Zend Framework: Autoloading module resources in config.ini?

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, configuration-files, bootstrapping, zend-application

Is it possible, to configure the following behaviour in application.ini?

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap 
{
    protected function _initAdminModuleAutoloader()
    {

    $this->_resourceLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Admin',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin',
    ));
        $this->_resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
            'model' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model',
                'path'      => 'models'
            )
        ));
}

}
?>
```

If so, can you please show us an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Was the example useful?  Have you seen it?

Comment: have the same question. Travis your reply doesnt answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of pointers.  First you should have the below line in your application.ini file.

```
resources.modules.admin = "enabled"
```

That will make sure that the following function in Zend_Application_Resource_Modules runs

```
public function init()
{
    $bootstrap = $this->getBootstrap();
    $bootstrap->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $front = $bootstrap->getResource('FrontController');

    $modules = $front->getControllerDirectory();
    $default = $front->getDefaultModule();
    $curBootstrapClass = get_class($bootstrap);
    foreach ($modules as $module => $moduleDirectory) {
        $bootstrapClass = $this->_formatModuleName($module) . '_Bootstrap';
        if (!class_exists($bootstrapClass, false)) {
            $bootstrapPath  = dirname($moduleDirectory) . '/Bootstrap.php';
            if (file_exists($bootstrapPath)) {
                $eMsgTpl = 'Bootstrap file found for module "%s" but bootstrap class "%s" not found';
                include_once $bootstrapPath;
                if (($default != $module)
                    && !class_exists($bootstrapClass, false)
                ) {
                    throw new Zend_Application_Resource_Exception(sprintf(
                        $eMsgTpl, $module, $bootstrapClass
                    ));
                } elseif ($default == $module) {
                    if (!class_exists($bootstrapClass, false)) {
                        $bootstrapClass = 'Bootstrap';
                        if (!class_exists($bootstrapClass, false)) {
                            throw new Zend_Application_Resource_Exception(sprintf(
                                $eMsgTpl, $module, $bootstrapClass
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        if ($bootstrapClass == $curBootstrapClass) {
            // If the found bootstrap class matches the one calling this
            // resource, don't re-execute.
            continue;
        }

        $moduleBootstrap = new $bootstrapClass($bootstrap);
        $moduleBootstrap->bootstrap();
        $this->_bootstraps[$module] = $moduleBootstrap;
    }

    return $this->_bootstraps;
}
```

In the above function your module bootstrap is called. You need to have a module bootstrap file in /application/modules/admin called Bootstrap.php with the following code in it:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{


}
```

I'm going to skip a few steps but if you trace through the inheritance classes this will lead to the following function being called in Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader

```
public function initDefaultResourceTypes()
{
    $basePath = $this->getBasePath();
    $this->addResourceTypes(array(
        'dbtable' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model_DbTable',
            'path'      => 'models/DbTable',
        ),
        'mappers' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model_Mapper',
            'path'      => 'models/mappers',
        ),
        'form'    => array(
            'namespace' => 'Form',
            'path'      => 'forms',
        ),
        'model'   => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model',
            'path'      => 'models',
        ),
        'plugin'  => array(
            'namespace' => 'Plugin',
            'path'      => 'plugins',
        ),
        'service' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Service',
            'path'      => 'services',
        ),
        'viewhelper' => array(
            'namespace' => 'View_Helper',
            'path'      => 'views/helpers',
        ),
        'viewfilter' => array(
            'namespace' => 'View_Filter',
            'path'      => 'views/filters',
        ),
    ));
    $this->setDefaultResourceType('model');
}
```

All of the above resource types will be covered by default for every module that you follow this pattern for. Any others that you need will need to be customized in a bootstrap file.

Comment: Thank you Travis. It's a good approach!
I was thinking about something simpler like this:

resources.frontcontroller.namespaces.viewfilter.ns = "View_Filter"
resources.frontcontroller.namespaces.viewfilter.path = 
"views/filters"

I suppose this kind of configuration is not available yet for Zend_Application. Maybe in a nearer future....

Comment: Well that is pretty simple.  

You only need the line 

resources.modules.admin = "enabled"


and the empty bootstrap file.

Zend_Application takes care of the rest for you.  I was just tracing through the actual Zend code for you that sets this up by default.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Zend Framework Version 1.10.4 with a default project configuration. I activate all Modules in my application.ini with the following line:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

Its important that you have a Bootstrap.php in your module directory. Without that, my models wasn't loaded correctly. The URL in your Browser seems to be case sensitive. For example: http://example.com/Admin/controller/action

So, it should work...